# Переменные окружения

Tags: windows-7

Добавляю переменные окружения или изменения, а получить их значение (например из cmd) могу только после перезагрузки системы. Как избежать ее и пользоваться переменными? (Win7/64 Ultimate)

Comment: а ка вы их получаете?

Comment: А может просто перезапустить cmd (если Вы меняете их в чём-то, что в прежних виндах -- win7 я не видел -- было system, то в открытой сессии cmd Вы изменений не заметите.

Comment: естественно я ее перезагружал и даже под админом запускал) но увы и ах(

Comment: 2 ProkletyiPirat:
забил путь в переменную, по этому пути есть приложение... в cmd делаю переход в эту директорию:
cd %direction%